# Why does capacitor value changes when capacitor is DC biased?

Tags: capacitor, dc, bias

I have seen ceramic capacitor value varying under various DC biased levels. Dc biased was a huge factor as capacitor value is reduced by 50% almost? Why?

Comment: This is the cause of many design issues. If you are looking at a datasheet or reference design doc, it will call out suggested capacitor values. Some datasheets were tested with these nominal values, and so will work fine. But others assume that you will over-specify your caps so that the effective (biased) capacitance is what they asked for. Usually, there's no way of knowing what the assumptions are. Sometimes it helps to compare the datasheet against the Eval Board (if they have one).  I don't know of a good answer.  I'm looking forward to hearing other people respond.

Comment: http://www.niccomp.com/help/VoltageCoefficientofCapacitors-032012-R1.pdf This is an interesting document for the change in C with V

Comment: @Andy aka: the link doesn't work anymore. Do you know another link with the same content?

Comment: http://www.niccomp.com/resource/files/ceramic/VoltageCoefficientofCapacitors-032012-R1.pdf

Comment: I never saw the original, so I can't guarantee that's the same. It has the same filename though!

Answer (score 12):

Murata has a pretty interesting [explanation on its FAQ](http://www.murata.com/products/capacitor/design/faq/mlcc/property/05_more.html) section about what is going on. I will quote the most relevant parts here for future reference.

The characteristic of change in capacitance according to the applied voltage is called "DC (direct current) bias characteristic."

[image]

**The mechanism of DC bias characteristic**

In the high dielectric constant capacitor type of monolithic ceramic capacitors, at present mainly BaTiO3 (barium titanate) is used as a principal component of high dielectric.
As shown below, BaTiO3 has a perovskite shaped crystal structure and above the Curie temperature it becomes a cubic shape with Ba2+ ions to the vertices, O2- ion to face center and Ti4+ ion in a body centered position.

[image]

At the Curie temperature (approx 125°C) or more, it has a cubic crystal structure, and below the Curie temperature and within an ambient temperature range, one axis (axis C) stretches and other the axes shrink and turn to a tetragonal crystal structure.

In this case, polarization occurs as a result of the unit shift of axially elongated Ti4+ ion crystal. This polarization occurs without applying an external electric field or pressure, and is known as "spontaneous polarization." As explained above, a characteristic that has a spontaneous polarization and a property of changing orientation of spontaneous polarization by an external electric field to reverse is called "ferroelectricity."

The reversal of the spontaneous polarization per unit volume is equivalent to relative permittivity. Relative permittivity is observed as a capacitance.
**Without a DC voltage, spontaneous polarization can happen freely. However, when a DC voltage is externally applied, spontaneous polarization is tied to the direction of the electric field in the dielectric, and independent reversal of spontaneous polarization is inhibited. As a result, the capacitance becomes lower than before applying the bias.**

Comment: Pretty interesting answer dude +1

Comment: But your graph stops at 6V with a significant -ve slope.  What will happen to ceramics decoupling a common +/- 15V op amp?  The %age change will be huge!  What to do?

Comment: @PaulUszak: The graph is not common to all MLCC. Any 100nF 25V X7R of your choice may look way different. Or choose a Class-I cap, those do not exhibit this kind of DC bias capacitance loss.

Comment: Does this also apply to electrolytic caps ?

Comment: @VanGo: No, at least not to this extense.