# Capacitor actual value with DC bias

Tags: capacitor, dc

I did find [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103785/why-does-capacitor-value-changes-when-capacitor-is-dc-biased) which explained why the capacitor is affected by the DC bias, however, my question is more on the application.

Let's say I have a capacitor for which I have the DC bias characteristic (Cap Charge [%] in function of DC Bias [VDC]) such as follow:

[image: DC bias characteristic]

Now, let's say I set the capacitor voltage to a certain value, i.e. 5V and I try to maintain it through a feedback loop. What is the DC Bias induce? Is it 5V? What is VDC?

It may sounds like a stupid question, but I kinda struggle with the notations...

Comment: A schematic to show context would help considerably.

Comment: Are you asking: I make a feedback loop to set V(cap) = 5 V DC, will there then be 5 V Dc across the capacitor? If the loop is working: then yes because the loop sets it to 5 V DC.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Assuming it works, and the value is kept within a window of +/- 10%. i.e. The voltage accross the capacitor is not constant but varying randomly (noise) between 4.5 and 5.5V. The mean value can be computed, and it is the DC Bias, correct? Thus, to figure out the True capacity, I can simply look to the corresponding value for the mean voltage?

Comment: Sure then you can use the mean value. Ideally your circuit should not be that sensitive to the capacitor's value, if it is then the tolerance of the capacitor will give you issues as well. There are **always** component variations, a proper design should be able to cope with that (be stable, function etc.). For high accuracy you would generally rely on trimming and/or calibration.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks, it does answer my question :) I do rely on calibration, but the question is: is it really needed? And that's what I'm trying to figure out :)

Comment: If you need calibration: determine component tolerances and then calculate what the minimum and maximum values of your circuit are. If that is within specification: no calibration needed. If it is not: you might need calibration. Never decide that calibration is needed (or not) without doing the proper calculations, never, ever. The proof is in the numbers.

Comment: The left axis of your graph is "cap **change** %", not "cap charge %" like you wrote in your text.

Comment: Just as an aside, if you use a capacitor that's not ceramic, like a polymer tantalum for example, the capacitance is stable with DC bias.

Comment: Just to add to other answers, your specific example is a \$16\:\text{V}\$, \$10\:\mu\text{F}\$,  X5R 1206 cap. These have very much reduced dielectric layer thicknesses, which means lots more voltage stress on the dielectric, which means a stronger voltage coefficient -- as shown. If you were to choose a much smaller value, say \$100\:\text{nF}\$ for example, the variation in capacitance with respect to the bias voltage would be much flatter because of the increased dielectric layer thickness allowed.

Comment: @JohnD Thanks, I've already read this somewhere else, nice to have the confirmation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is a DC bias

DC bias is a measurement of the average voltage on a wire on which can "ride" a signal, should this wire transmit data, and noise.
Its unit is DC Volts, or VDC. You can remember it because it is the direct voltage on the conductor.

#### Variation of stored charge as  a function of DC bias

Onto the phenomenon you describe in your question : as the signal varies, the capacitance "seen" by it *will* vary, introducing nonlinearities. **But**, the DC bias being most of the time large compared to the signal (or noise) voltage, they will be small.

Thus, you *can* use the DC bias as an effective voltage with which to consider the effective capacitance of your component, **if and only if** the voltage across the capacitor does not vary too much.

For example, if a \$5\$ to \$-5\$ volts audio signal had a \$7\$ volts DC bias and one end of the capacitor was grounded, the overall voltage would range from \$2\$ volts to \$12\$, which is a huge variation. You should not rely on a time constant or a precise capacitance then. If it was a \$\pm 200 \text{ mV}\$ signal on the other hand, you most likely could.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the capacitor at the output of a buck or a boost converter, than you are fine using the output voltage as a reference to use in the posted graph. 
Also if you use a capacitor with more than twice the rated than applied voltage this change should be negligible.