# Different capacitors between VCC and ground required for different sensors and components

Tags: arduino, pcb, atmega

I am designing a custom board with a ATmega16u2. In the specifications of the linear voltage regulator, a 10uF capacitor is required between the regulated voltage and ground. A 1uF is required between the power and ground for the ATmega16u2, and a 100nF is required between the BMP388 power and ground. Do I use the highest value capacitor, or do I use all 3 capacitors in the circuit.

Comment: Which regulator? And how are the devices connected? What types of caps being used? The answer will also depend on how far apart the devices are on a PCB.

Comment: Also related/useful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/400683/2028